# Matrix multiplication commutativity question

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Can anyone help me understand why does the following equality hold:
$$
\left(\mathbf{X}^{\prime} \mathbf{X}\right)^{-1} \mathbf{X}^{\prime}\left(\sigma_{\varepsilon}^{2} \mathbf{I}\right) \mathbf{X}\left(\mathbf{X}^{\prime} \mathbf{X}\right)^{-1} =\sigma_{\varepsilon}^{2}\left(\mathbf{X}^{\prime} \mathbf{X}\right)^{-1}\left(\mathbf{X}^{\prime} \mathbf{X}\right)\left(\mathbf{X}^{\prime} \mathbf{X}\right)^{-1}
$$

I thought matrix multiplication is not commutative.

Comment: Minor point.  "Not commutative" means "not always commutative" in other words: you cannot rely on it.  It does not "never commutative".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The operations used are quite simple. (1) Scalar $\sigma_\epsilon^2$ can be pulled out in front of the matrix product, (2) identity matrix $I$ is the identity element of matrix multiplication and can be left out, (3) matrix multiplication is associative and so the grouping $(X'X)$ is possible.

Answer (score 0):

All multiples of the identity matrix commute with anything, since all they do is rescale any conformable matrix on the left or right. This, combined with the associativity of matrix multiplication, allows us to move that multiple to the leftmost position, where we can remove the explicit identity.

Answer (score 0):

I understand now. It's because $\sigma_{ε}^2$ is a scalar, so it can be moved to anywhere

Comment: No, it is not because it is a constant. It is because it is a scalar.

Comment: @KBS yes that's very true. thanks a lot for the correction.